# I am getting warning message of this "This site ahead contains malware" in google chrome

Tags: magento-2.1, url

After I installed the local setup for Magento 2.1.16 with the Nginx server. When I try to visit my site in chrome it notifies me with the site ahead contains malware.
I have tried removing all third-party extensions.
I have seen some answers, they were saying to scan for malware from online free sites. How could I do that for my local setup?
Could anybody help?[image]